# Generic path to a module in Magento

Tags: magento

Is there a generic way to receive the path to a Magento module? I want to link to an configuration file in the /etc folder in one of my modules.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can ask for paths with getModuleDir method

```
Mage::getModuleDir('Model', 'Your_Extension');
Mage::getModuleDir('Block', 'Your_Extension');
Mage::getModuleDir('Helper', 'Your_Extension');
Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Your_Extension');
Mage::getModuleDir('etc', 'Your_Extension');
```

Comment: Top! Just to complete: `getModuleDir()` does not add a trailing `/`

Comment: This answer is not totally correct, you can't pass 'Model' as first param. You should concat it after and pass '' as first param. Pay attention to answer of user user649650.

Comment: yeah if you like to be nerdy :D just translate Your_Extension as namespace_extension

Answer (score 6):

getModuleDir only works where the first parameter is 'etc', 'controllers', 'sql', or 'locale'. Of course, you could just pass in a '' as the first parameter and append 'Model'/'Block'/'Helper' to the returned value.